# month on month records

Tags: mysql, datetime

Apologies if my question is structured incorrectly, first time user.

I would like to get all records from the current DateTime and previous month for the same date range e.g. 01st-15th. The date field has a timestamp so would like all the records to the hour and minute.

```
select
'Total' as 'Measure',
sum(pa.amount) as 'Current Month'
from pay as pa
inner join mem as me on pa.me_id = me.me_id 
where pa.pa_completed between last_day(current_date() - interval 1 month) + 
interval 1 day 
and if(current_date() = current_date(),current_timestamp(),current_date())
group by 1

union all    

select
'Total' as 'Measure',
sum(pa.amount) as 'Last Month'
from pay as pa
inner join mem as me on pa.me_id = me.me_id 
where pa.pa_completed between last_day(current_date() - interval 2 month) + 
interval 1 day
and if(current_date() = current_date(),current_timestamp() - interval 1 
month,current_date() - interval 1 month)
group by 1
```

The where clause in the above codes does not seem to be returning the correct records. I have cross checked the output on both sets of SQL to our admin system and the figures are slightly off.

Is there something I am doing wrong in the code? or is there a better solution to get the output I am after?

I will be using the above code on a dashboard so the current_date() will change everyday.

Comment: "does not seem to be returning..." is not a helpful description. Please explain what it returns, and what it should return.

Comment: This `if(current_date() = current_date(),current_timestamp(),current_date())` looks a bit wierd because `current_date() = current_date()` is always true

Comment: What do you want to have happen--what date ranges do you want reported--if you run this on 30-Mar-2018?  (It's a trick question having to do with months having different numbers of days.)

Comment: You should provide us with a sqlfiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with example tables and example data. And also post a acsii data table with expected output based on that example data. This way we don't have to reverse engineer your SQL query and you will get better help.